# Encoded Absolute URL

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

When creating an email including the Encoded Absolute URL, it works and opens the page in Edit view.  However I am trying to gt this to work in View instead where the form cannot be edited.

Is there a way to change the way that this Absolute URL opens the form?

[image]

New View - [image]

Email link - New  - [image]

Thanks

Comment: What is the current string you are using? Just the Encoded Absolute URL?

Comment: Yes, i have added an image for the way I have done this.  I am trying Kevin's suggestion at the moment - but I am new and rubbish with SharePoint and info-path.  Will keep you updated on my progress/solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a form view that is read only(`Properties->General->Read-only`).

Then add your link with `&DefaultView=yourReadonlyView`
[image]

Comment: Sorry i still didnt get this to work - i have added a picture of what i think you asked me to do in the question, sorry, im clueless with this kind of thing

Comment: I made a rule on my submit button to switch to the read only view, but when the form is opened in my library, its in edit mode. - And the link in email (through workflows) dont open edit mode, i get a technical error - see screenshots above for what i tried to do.

Comment: The link URL should be something like:http://servername.com/subsite/_layouts/15/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=theEncodedAbsoluteURL&OpenIn=Browser&DefaultView=yourReadonly; And click Properties under your view name to set up as Read-only(nameing as readonly is not enough); reference: https://olenicksharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/add-a-link-to-a-list-item-in-a-sharepoint-designer-workflow-email/